# ZSH is set up to use aliases, but now the script I run does not honor them

Tags: shell, zsh

Running zsh locally and installed oh-my-zsh.

~/.zprofile:

```
# Added by Toolbox App
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/boxcee/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts"

# Github
export GITHUB_TOKEN=xxx

# Homebrew
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

~/.zshrc:

```
# Podman
alias docker=podman
alias docker-compose=podman-compose

# Python
alias python=python3
alias pip=pip3
```

Now I am trying to run the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

docker version
```

and get this error:

```
./test.sh:3: command not found: docker
```

I don't understand why I get it.
Running the command separately in my ZSH works just fine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with zsh, but in bash your aliases are not loaded by default in a non-interactive shell.

Comment: .zshrc is only read for interactive shells. See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files

Comment: In a bash script where I want my aliases to work, I add these two lines: `shopt -s expand_aliases` and `source ~/.aliases_bash` and then they work. But it's not best practice to do this. Instead, you probably should define what you need in the script itself.

Comment: Did you actually source your .zshrc from your script?

Comment: @joanis : For bash, this is necessary. In zsh alias expansion is always active in scripts.

Comment: @user1934428 OK, good to know. So the solution is only half the same between zsh and bash.

Comment: Instead of using aliases I should perhaps create some symbolic links instead? what do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run your script as an executable, it runs in a subshell. Since aliases are not exported to the environment, the subshell cannot import them. If you want aliases to be retained, then you should `source` your script instead, which causes it to run in the same shell from which you call it.